# Are there any missable/limited recruitable monsters?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

It looks like it's possible to get multiple of most common monsters - are there any that this isn't the case for?  Are there any I need to be careful not to waste the limited supply of on infusions, or any that can be missed entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i am aware there are no monsters you can miss in the sense of never being able to get them after a certain plot event.

There are 10 monsters that you can only get once. The first 3 you get by fighting. The other 7 by getting their crystal with improved Moogle throw. Here's the list:

1. Gigantuar.
2. Twilight Odin
3. Golden Chocobo
4. Nanochu
5. Chichu
6. Silver Chocobo
7. Leyak
8. Rangda
9. Cactuarama
10. Cactuarina

Comment: Accepted - grats on 1k :)

Comment: 11 days must be some kind of record no ?

Comment: Thanks to the [Valfodr](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Valfodr_%28Boss%29) Coliseum battle as part of the *Perpetual Battlefield* DLC, you can now retrieve these monster crystals more than once.