# Can I capture monsters more than once?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I noticed there was an option to release monsters, does this mean you can recapture them again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Most* monsters can be caught more than once using catch-and-release. Additionally, you can capture multiple Black, Blue, Green, Purple, White, and Regular Chocobos.

There are, however, a number of monsters you can only capture once ever,<sup>1</sup> as [Serge Bekenkamp's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/51701/3389) mentions:

#### Fightable

- Gigantuar
- Golden Chocobo
- Twilight Odin

#### Retrievable using *Mog's Manifestation*/Moogle Throw

- Cactuarama
- Cactuarina
- Chichu
- Leyak
- Nanochu
- Rangda
- Silver Chocobo

#### Notes

<sup>Note 1:</sup> Unless you purchase the *Perpetual Battlefield* DLC, which allows you to fight [Valfodr](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Valfodr_%28Boss%29). The drops for defeating Valfodr at his various levels include monster crystals for the normally unique tamable monsters.

Comment: Is there a list of monsters that cannot be caught more than once?

Comment: @Mr.November One step ahead of you: just completed my edit :)

Comment: Gigantuar is incorrect. If you get a crystal the first time you kill him, you can release him and obtain him in the second two fights. You will not be able to do this after having the three fights though, even through rolling back the timeline

Comment: You can re-capture Lightning, Amodar and Omega.